# How to keep selenium webdriver running as part of before_tag hook using fixture in behave framework?

Tags: python, selenium, testing, automation, bdd

I am using [behave](https://behave.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html) framework for testing and some features files do not require a browser to run against. So I am trying to use fixtures with tags as described in https://behave.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tutorial.html#controlling-things-with-tags. The problem is that the `CLEANUP-FIXTURE PART` ran right after the driver is started.

environment.py

```py
@fixture
def selenium_webdriver(context):
    # -- SETUP-FIXTURE PART:
    context.driver = webdriver.Remote(
        command_executor='http://my-selenium-server:4444/wd/hub',
        desired_capabilities=DesiredCapabilities.CHROME)
    context.driver.set_page_load_timeout(30)
    context.driver.maximize_window()
    yield context.driver
    # -- CLEANUP-FIXTURE PART:
    context.driver.quit()

fixture_registry1 = {
    "fixture.selenium_webdriver": selenium_webdriver
}

def before_tag(context, tag):
    if tag.startswith("fixture.selenium_webdriver"):
        return use_fixture_by_tag(tag, context, fixture_registry1)
```

test.feature

```
@fixture.selenium_webdriver
Feature: Test

  Scenario: My Scenario
    Given Something
    When I do anything
    Then Something happens
```

During scenarios execution, the driver starts successfully, however, it ends right after. I have tried to comment the lines under `CLEANUP-FIXTURE PART:` to keep it running, but the behave kind of lost connection with the selenium session. Any thoughts on how to only starts selenium webdriver for specifics tags and features?

Answer (score 1):

Ok, reading again the documentation I found a solution that worked for me. Here is what I did:

environment.py

```py
@fixture
def selenium_webdriver(context):
    # -- SETUP-FIXTURE PART:
    context.driver = webdriver.Remote(
        command_executor='http://my-selenium-server:4444/wd/hub',
        desired_capabilities=DesiredCapabilities.CHROME)
    context.driver.set_page_load_timeout(30)
    context.driver.maximize_window()
    yield context.driver
    # -- CLEANUP-FIXTURE PART:
    context.driver.quit()

fixture_registry1 = {
    "fixture.selenium_webdriver": selenium_webdriver
}

def before_feature(context, feature):
    if "fixture.selenium_webdriver" in feature.tags:
        use_fixture(selenium_webdriver, context)
```

test.feature

```
@fixture.selenium_webdriver
Feature: Test

  Scenario: My Scenario
    Given Something
    When I do anything
    Then Something happens
```

Using `before_feature` hook instead of `before_tag` did the trick.